# How to run IE10 and IE9 simultaneously on Windows 7 without using VMs?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Now that it's possible, I'd like to install IE10 on my Win7 machine.  However, I need to continue to run IE9 for testing purposes.  Has anyone figured out a way to do this without using the VMs?  For some reason this issue is impervious to googling...

Comment: Microsoft release virtual machines which are centered around testing IE in various configures.

Comment: Using the Developers Tools (F12) you can switch to all recent versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an app called [IE Tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

It'll allow you to use all IE versions back to 5.5, but, ZippyV's solution (using developer tools) would work pretty much as well (better in some cases)

Comment: This will not work for IE10. `"Note for IE10 : IE10 is not available on IETester if it is not the default IE version installed on the system. So IE10 is only available on Windows 8 machines."`

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it simultaneously that i am aware of, but if you want to use both without using a vim, simply uninstall IE10 everytime you need to use IE9; yes it is tedious, annoying, and not ideal. 
You actually can't "uninstall", but when you go to uninstall software, click on the option for windows updates, you'll find your ie10 install there.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried IETester and just crashes every tab i try to open. I am going to try the Virtualization tools provided here - https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

A vm for instance on VirtualBox should do the job. I will update the answer if it works.

Of course even if it works you need a VM for each version of IE

Comment: A year later and I had the same experience with IETester. Crashes on 9 out of 10 page/tab loads. Unusable as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Start IE11
type f12 key for dev bar then : 
/ Emu / UserAgent / IE9

Solved my problem using Adobe Flash based website...

Thanks to @ZyppyV
(
[How to run IE10 and IE9 simultaneously on Windows 7 without using VMs?](https://superuser.com/questions/558954/how-to-run-ie10-and-ie9-simultaneously-on-windows-7-without-using-vms#comment680779_558954)
)